# Why is Griffiths using ordinary power series to solve Hydrogen atom problem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, singularities, hydrogen

The hydrogen atom problem leads to a differential equation of the form
$$\rho\frac{d^2v}{d\rho^2}+2(\ell+1-\rho)\frac{dv}{d\rho}+[\rho_0-2(\ell+1)]v=0\tag{4.61}$$ where $\rho_0$ is a constant. In order to solve this ODE, Griffiths assumes an ordinary power series solution about $\rho=0$: $$v(\rho)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}c_j\rho^j.\tag{4.62}$$ But $\rho=0$ is not an ordinary point but a regular singular point. Therefore, in general, we expect a solution in the form of a generalized power series $$v(\rho)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}c_j\rho^{j+\sigma}$$ where $\sigma$ is a number to be determined. Why is Griffiths using ordinary power series?

Comment: No reason except that he knows in advance that a fractional $\sigma$ is not going to arise in the solution.

Comment: Isn't he also assuming $\sigma=0$? Because if for example, $\sigma$ were a positive integer, the series would not start with $\rho^0$. He assumes that the series starts with $\rho^0$. The only way out that I can think of is that we must use the generalized series solution and show that only $\sigma=0$ is allowed. Am I correct?

Comment: At that stage, he hasn't technically ruled out $c_{0}=0$, for example, although he has engineered things so that the series does indeed start at $j=0$.  He has effectively already pulled out the the $\rho^{\sigma}$ factor by defining $u(\rho)=\rho^{\ell+1}e^{-\rho}v(\rho)$.

Comment: But even after pulling out $\rho^{\ell+1}$, the equation satisfied by the interpolating function $v(\rho)$ carries a regular singular point at $\rho=0$. Let us forget about H-atom, and just look at the equation satisfied by $v(\rho)$. Then the solution that one expects about $\rho=0$ should be generalized power series. Isn't it?

Comment: Sure, but as I wrote, Griffiths knows ahead of time what power series will work, so he uses it.  He doesn't expect students taking undergraduate quantum mechanics to know anything about singular points of a differential equation, so he avoids the question by not introducing $\sigma$ at all.  If you were worried about *proving* the completeness of the solutions of the Schrödinger equation, then you would need to worry about whether $\sigma=0$ finds all the solutions—but that is a *massively* harder problem, well beyond the level even of standard *graduate* quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few steps earlier Griffiths has derived the asymptotic
behavior of $u(\rho)$ for large radii ($\rho\to\infty$)
$$u(\rho) \sim Ae^{-\rho} \tag{4.58}$$
and for small radii ($\rho\to0$)
$$u(\rho) \sim C\rho^{\ell+1}. \tag{4.59}$$

Then, for finding the exact solution $u(\rho)$ at all radii
in between (i.e. not only for very small or very large $\rho$)
he made the further approach
$$u(\rho)=\rho^{\ell+1}e^{-\rho}v(\rho). \tag{4.60}$$

That means, from (4.59) and (4.60) you already know
the asymptotic behavior of $v(\rho)$ for small radii ($\rho\to0$):
$$v(\rho)\sim C$$
and not
$$v(\rho) \sim C \rho^\sigma  \quad\text{with }\sigma\ne 0$$